# Modifying LaTeX Table of Contents to add a period after chapter/table/figure number

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I need to add a period after the chapter/table/figure number in each line in Table of Contents/LoT/LoF.

ie, right now it shows:

```
TABLES
1   first
2   second
```

but I need it to show:

```
TABLES
1.  first
2.  second
```

I know this can be done with the tocloft package, however, that package is conflicting with the latex style I'm using, with the error: `\c@lotdepth is already defined`. (The style is an old style for my university's thesis format, but it's slightly out of date, so I need to make some changes to get it right.

I also found that I can change thechapter/thetable/thefigure, so those contain periods. However, that then messes up my references and has the period in all of my references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer. The \addcontentslines{...} is what adds the actual text, and because latex formatting is difficult to follow when there's fifty statements, I was missing it. Adding a period into there took care of it.

Comment: you should make sure you don't get a `..` between the chapter and section figures... something like `1..2` I tried to do this for the article class, and it turned out to be a dirty, dirty hack.

Comment: @Mica: when I was redefining \thechapter, that's what happened, now I'm only changing it when I add the content line for chapters. ...

Comment: *"because latex formatting is difficult to follow when there's fifty statements"* Roger that. When I have to do that, I always kill some trees and sit down with a cup of coffee to pour over the resulting hardcopy. For some reason, I miss the critical bit less often that way...

Answer (score 4):

```
\let \savenumberline \numberline
\def \numberline#1{\savenumberline{#1.}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a pretty trivial hack of the class file itself. The contents line format is defined somewhere in there. Just find it and add the `.`.

My (limited!) experience with class files is that even pretty rough edged ones have readable identifiers, so you won't need to understand all the nasty inner workings of the TeX.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 since it's on the right track, though when the class file is ~1500 lines it's difficult to just find the point the period needs to go. Anyways ... I did find the place now....